# Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $0<b<1$. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(nb^n)=0$ using $\ln$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $0<b<1$. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(nb^n)=0$ using the $\ln$ and the binomial theorem.

**Using the binomial theorem**

$b := 1/(1 + a)$ where $a > 0$. Since $(1 + a)^n > \frac{1}
2{}n(n − 1)a^2$, we have
$0<nb^n ≤n/[\frac{1}
2{}n(n − 1)a^2]≤2/[(n−1)a^2]$. Thus $\lim(nbn)=0$

**Using the $\ln$**

How can I prove it by this way?

Comment: Not sure why you eant to use $\ln$ since the first proof is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $\log(nb^{n})=\log n+n\log b<n^{1/2}+n\log b=(1+n^{1/2}\log b)n^{1/2}$ and $\log b<0$ so $n^{1/2}\log b\rightarrow-\infty$. Then take exponential.